# How to get singleton instance from a class name as string

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection, singleton

I am running into a strange problem. I have an interface, whose implementations tend to be stateless. So, I want them to be singletons.

I get the implementation class names as strings. For example

```
String clazz = "com.foo.Bar";
```

I have a rules factory to obtain instances of `IRule` implementations.

```
public class RulesFactory {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RulesFactory.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends IRule> T getRuleInstance(String clazz) {
        try {
            Class<?> ruleObject = Class.forName(clazz);
            Method factoryMethod = ruleObject.getMethod("getInstance");
            return (T) factoryMethod.invoke(null);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error("ClassNotFoundException", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error("IllegalAccessException", e);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logger.error("SecurityException", e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            logger.error("NoSuchMethodException", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("IllegalArgumentException", e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            logger.error("InvocationTargetException", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above code throws `NullPointerException` if the class doesn't have a static `getInstance()` method. In Java 6 i can't use static methods in interfaces. I don't want to create multiple instances of `IRule` implementations. If I can enforce a static method and invoke that static method I will get the cashed instance. But I am unable to do this. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Another idea: have the implementations with constructors package protected. Have them in the same package as RulesFactory, then based on clazz create with "new" the implementation and store it in a map by class name. Always check the map before creating new instance.

Comment: Null is a valid value to pass to invoke **if** the method is static. So check your `getInstance()` methods.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes. It is valid. But how to enforce getInstance to be implemented by clients and that too as static method?

Comment: Enforce it with documentation and good programming practices.

Comment: @BRS seeing your reply to Kayaman I feel you should edit your  question to put that as your concern and not the NPE.

Comment: @rajesh I am sorry, I didn't get you. My question is correct I think.

Comment: @Kayaman Thank you. But I was just wondering is there a way to do it programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions with different pros and cons:

1. Don't use `static` methods. If the method isn't static, you can add it to `IRule` and therefore enforce that the method exists.
2. Check the qualifiers of `factoryMethod` and throw a descriptive exception when they aren't `static`

For solution #1, you need a `Map<String,IRule>`. When `getRuleInstance()` is called, check the map for an instance. If there is none, use the method from the interface to create one and put it into the map. This way, you can make the instances singletons.

At the same time, you can get all fields of the instance and make sure all of them are `final` to enforce the statelessness.

If your application is multi-threaded, make sure you use a concurrent map and synchronize properly.

Example code:

```
private Map<String, IRule> rules = Maps.newHashMap();

public static <T extends IRule> T getRuleInstance(String clazz) {
    try {
        synchronized( rules ) {
            IRule result = rules.get(clazz);
            if(null == result) {
                result = clazz.newInstance();
                rules.put(clazz, result);
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T tmp = (T) result;
            return tmp;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log( "Unable to create IRule for {}", clazz );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, it has become a 'chicken and egg' issue with choice one. Unless I have an instance I can't call invoke method, and then there is no point in calling getInstance(). Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Actually I am trying to instantiate the implementation using the Bill Pugh pattern. So, it is creating trouble that two instance are created. One for calling invoke and the other by calling getInstance().

Comment: for #1, call `ruleObject.newInstance()`. Actually, you should rename `ruleObject` to `ruleType`.

Comment: But, I am not using the interface right? ): Is there a solution?

Comment: There are two solutions: 1. You can use a new interface `IRuleFactory` which creates instances of `IRule`. This way, you can mix stateful and stateless rules (factories can either return the same instance or create new ones). 2. Instead of calling `getInstance()`, you create the instance in `getRuleInstance()` and put it in the map.

Answer (score 1):

You are making your life unnecessary hard.

If you remember the great “`enum` singleton pattern” and require that all implementors use it, e.g.

```
public enum Foo implements IRule
{
  INSTANCE;

  // IRule implementation methods here

  public String toString() { return "the sole Foo instance"; }
}
```

the entire `RulesFactory` becomes as simple as:

```
private static final ConcurrentMap<String, IRule> instancesMap
                                             = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, IRule>();

public static IRule getRuleInstance(String clazz) {
  try {
      IRule iRuleInstance=instancesMap.get(clazz);
      if(iRuleInstance!=null) return iRuleInstance;
      Class<? extends IRule> ruleObject=Class.forName(clazz).asSubclass(IRule.class);
      IRule[] enumConstants=ruleObject.getEnumConstants();
      if(enumConstants==null || enumConstants.length!=1) {
        logger.error("InvalidClassException",
                     new InvalidClassException(clazz, "not a singleton enum"));
        return null;
      }
      iRuleInstance=enumConstants[0];
      instancesMap.put(clazz, iRuleInstance);
      return iRuleInstance;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("ClassNotFoundException", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The great thing about the  “`enum` singleton pattern” is that it already guarantees the singleton property, thus the code above doesn’t make any attempt to detect concurrent lookups as they are guaranteed to return the same single instance.