# How to solve this chicken and egg issue?

Tags: java, design-patterns, reflection

I saw similar questions here on SO, but, I am asking this question based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288579/how-to-get-singleton-instance-from-a-class-name-as-string/27288997#27288997).

I have implemented the suggestion given by the accepted answer but, still I see two instances being created. The goal is that I want an instance to be created only on a particular method call. I can't use static method in an interface with Java 6.

**The code I have tried**

```
private static final Map<String, IRule> instancesMap = new Hashtable<String, IRule>();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends IRule> T getRuleInstance(String clazz) {
    try {
        if (isInstanceCreated(clazz)) {
            T type = (T) instancesMap.get(clazz);
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Found a cashed instance of " + clazz + ". Returning " + type);
            }
            return type;
        } else {
            Class<?> ruleObject = Class.forName(clazz);
            Constructor<?> clazzConstructor = ruleObject.getDeclaredConstructor();
            /**
             * Hack encapsulation
             */
            clazzConstructor.setAccessible(true);
            IRule iRuleInstance = (IRule) clazzConstructor.newInstance();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("The instance of class " + clazz + " " + iRuleInstance + " has been created.");
            }
            instancesMap.put(clazz, iRuleInstance);
            return (T) iRuleInstance.getInstance();
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("ClassNotFoundException", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        logger.error("IllegalAccessException", e);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        logger.error("SecurityException", e);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        logger.error("NoSuchMethodException", e);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error("IllegalArgumentException", e);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        logger.error("InvocationTargetException", e);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        logger.error("InstantiationException", e);
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean isInstanceCreated(String clazz) {
    return instancesMap.containsKey(clazz);
}
```

Comment: Is your code multi-threaded? Because what you posted is not thread-safe.

Comment: @Jesper Yes. I am using Hashtable right?

Comment: Using `Hashtable` does not make it thread-safe.

Comment: @Jesper Can you please explain why? I think the Hashtable uses synchronization. Should I use ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: There is practically no (good) reason to use `Hashtable` these days; If you think what you need is a `Hashtable`, see if there's something newer (like `ConcurrentHashMap`) which works instead, because it'll be a lot better.

Comment: Since the methods of `Hashtable` are synchronized, there will be only one thread at a time executing a `Hashtable` method, but there is no synchronization across calls. You can have two threads entering your `getRuleInstance` method at the same time, both noticing that there is no instance yet, and then both create a new instance. You'll have to synchronize the `getRuleInstance` method.

Comment: @Jesper So, synchronizing getRuleInstance() and using ConcurrentHashMap would be better then.

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment if there's a cache hit, you return the contents of the cache (`instancesMap.get(clazz)`). But if no hit, you cache one thing (`instancesMap.put(clazz, iRuleInstance)`) and return another (`iRuleInstance.getInstance()`). That doesn't make sense.

Don't call `getInstance` after adding to map, just return it:

```
instancesMap.put(clazz, iRuleInstance);
return (T) iRuleInstance;
```

Or, do call getInstance, but cache it:

```
(T) instance = iRuleInstance.getInstance();
instancesMap.put(clazz, instance);
return (T) instance;
```

Either way you **must** return what you cache so that it matches your logic for a cache hit.

Comment: But, what about the interface contract? I can't enforce singletonness through interface. I want instance to be created on only method call.

Comment: I don't know. Put how you're calling it and what you expect. At the moment if there's a cache hit, you return the contents of the cache. But if no hit, you cache one thing and return another. That's confusing.

Comment: `newInstance()` is doing the creation, so I don't know what you mean?

Comment: I want an interface to enforce singleton pattern. In java 6. And use class name and get an instance from interface method using reflection.

Comment: I can't see your `IRule` interface. It's not on this question or the other. It sounds like a bad idea to enforce singleton by interface, but post it up anyway in question. What I can see is that cache is incorrect.

Comment: I've added another option that allows you to call your `getInstance`

Comment: But, iRuleInstance itself is an instance of the implementation right? I don't want that. ):

Comment: I've got no idea. I don't have enough of your code or what you want to achieve. But I do know you must return what you cache, to match your logic for a cache hit.

Comment: Do you really need to create these by string name by the way?

Comment: Yes. ):. Only that way.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason why you need to have the concrete implementation of `IRule`?-- what methods are you going to be using from the implementation? Can't they be generalised into the interface itself? If this is the case, you could just have a map of `Map<Class<? extends IRule>, IRule>` to manage your instances.

Comment: I think I stated my reason in the referenced question already.

Comment: I don't see any reason for returning concrete implementation classes: You only want them to be "stateless" and therefore you want them to be "singletons". First of all, non-singletons can be stateless and singletons can also have states. The only language-based reason why you would need the concrete class is to call the static `ImplClass.getInstance()`, which makes no sense: Just create a single factory for managing all of your instances so that if an instance of a given class was already created, you return a reference to that one. Now you only need to see the `IRule` interface.